# How to mock A/B test variant in an app that uses Google Experiments script and Angular with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking, protractor

I'm using Google Experiments for A/B testing and got the following script tag in `index.html` file:

`<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=id"></script>`

and the following code in my app's `run` method:

`$rootScope.abtest = window.cxApi? ? window.cxApi.chooseVariation() : 1`

What's the best way to mock `window.cxApi.chooseVariation()` return value in e2e Protractor test? Or maybe it would be easier to mock it if I moved this value from $rootScope to a service?